# How does glass create an electric field?

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen, dielectric

I'm reading from [Microchip's data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mXT1189T%20Touchscreen%20Controller%20Product%20Datasheet.pdf) regarding their MAXTouch microchip, which details on how to create a touchscreen compatible with their chip, and in discussing the "mechanical stackup" of a touchscreen it is noted that

> Front panel dielectric material has a direct bearing on sensitivity. Plastic front panels are usually suitable up to about 3 mm, and glass up to about 4 mm (dependent upon the screen size and layout). The thicker the front panel, the lower the signal-to-noise ratio of the measured capacitive changes and hence the lower the resolution of the touchscreen. **In general, glass front panels are near optimal because they conduct electric fields almost twice as easily as plastic panels**.

I'm unsure what this means that glass or plastic conducts electric fields. A typical mutual capacitive touchscreen consists of a set of x transmission lines underneath a set of y transmission lines (with space between them).

I thought that that space and the transmission lines is what causes the electric fields, not the glass which is on top of it all.

There's also a note which says

> Care should be taken using ultra-thin glass panels as retransmission effects can occur, which can significantly degrade performance

So I guess this means that you wouldn't want to try and use a touch screen with no glass/plastic overlay at all?

Comment: I expect that a material that "conducts electric fields" is an insulator. Conductors block electric fields so I guess plastic is about twice as conductive as glass (still not very).

Comment: You don't want fingers in direct contact with the conductive material because that could conduct ESD to the circuitry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In general, glass front panels are near optimal because they conduct electric fields almost twice as easily as plastic panels.

This means is Glass (\$\epsilon _R =4.7\$) has **twice** the relative permittivity of plastic ( \$\epsilon _R =2.3\$ ) in the materials preferred here. This applies to both mutual and direct capacitance.

*What is free space permittivity ?* 
  - about 9 picofarads per meter ( ~ 9 pF /m means means 9 pF  would be the capacitance of two hands with a gap of \$1/9^{th}\$ of the hand width.
*Why it is relative?* all insulators are dielectric but glass is still twice as much as plastic and more than 4 times air or a vacuum.

> ultra-thin glass panels as retransmission effects can occur

This means a partial discharge (PD) can occur and the charge buildup can create false sensing, which also may damage cells from the E field breakdown as breakdown threshold for example  >10kV/mm or 10V/um is approached with ultrathin glass < 1mm